# Jars Issues in Maven Spring Hibernate Project

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, maven-3, m2eclipse

I had made Web Application on Spring and Hibernate by taking reference from [Vaannila](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html)

When I specify lib name on pom.xml using eclipse, the maven repository could not include all the jars.

How can I include the jars on my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the maven [install:install](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) command which includes the jars into your maven repo

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=group_id -DartifactId=artifact_id -Dversion=version -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=path_to_jar

For this , you could try mvn package - maven will given an error asking use to use the above command - copy paste it , change the path and use it in your command prompt .

or

add the jar as an external jar - Right click your project in Eclipse - go to properties -->Build path -->Libraries -->Add external jars

To download from the central repo ,add the following to your pom

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
  <layout>default</layout>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
 </repository>
</repositories>
```

Hibernate and Hibernate annotations are separate jars . These are the dependencies I use . Try them .

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

To do this manually ,

Download hibernate-annotations  from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/) and save it in C:/temp or wherever you want. Then perform

mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate-annotations -Dversion=3.4.0.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:/temp/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar

Comment: Still, I had to specify the dependency details on pom.xml. My problem is after including the dependency, I am facing error  'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/Entity'

Comment: Do you have the hibernate annotations jar in your .m2 folder ? If not , include it using the install:install command . To access this dependency in your project using maven , you'll have to include it in your pom .

Comment: hibernate3.jar comes from hibernate distribution but this jar could not loaded in maven repository. kindly suggest.

Comment: See my edit . Also do an mvn eclipse:eclipse to bring this into the classpath if it does not happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

See [this Maven Spring Hibernate example project](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/).

Hopefully you will easily understand from there.