# Struts2+Spring Integration

Tags: spring, maven, struts2, glassfish, struts2-spring-plugin

Trying to integrate Struts2 and Spring in my application using Maven. I have placed all   the dependencies in Pom file which is related to Spring-web,Spring,Struts2-spring plugin

```
<!-- Spring framework --> 
     <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
 <type>jar</type>
 <version>2.5.6</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
 <version>2.5.6</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
 <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

and i have included the following in Web.xml file,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>  

     <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

When i running using Maven war file is generated and when i deploying my war    file in my server(glassfish) error message is showing like

```
"Error An error has occurred
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader. Please see server.log for more details."
```

So anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: few things, why you need Spring-web?? can you provide complete error log? In end my Question is why to use Spring-web and Struts2 since both are MVC based platform

Comment: Dear Umesh, I am new to Spring. My web application is working fine in Struts2. I want to use spring for DI in my application. So I am trying to integrating. so now u can able to understand my situation.  I just take the code from MKYong website and trying to find the integration.

Comment: @Umesh , he is using spring-web jar  for Struts integration . I think you are refering to  spring-webmvc which corresponds to Spring MVC framework .Both are different .

Comment: OK!! Just add spring-web jar in your class-path and i hope this should work as the issue is with spring-jar.Since you are using `2.2.3` just upgrade to spring 3.x version in place of `2.5.6`

Comment: @AravindA: yes i got that,just read it other way in first go :).y i hate this Spring set-up if i want to use DI why not to use only core.I guess trying to use OSGI they are going back-ward steps.

Comment: QUmesh I guess he needs more than just DI - spring-web gives access to the WebApplicationContext and enhances support for request handling . I agree with you that Spring is trying to cover too much in one go :)

Comment: Add a spring-context dependency.

Comment: Also, what's your specific need for spring-web? In general you won't need it except for a few very specific things.

Answer (score 0):

ContextLoader is in the Spring-web jar . The error is because this class definition could not be found . Check if this dependency is present in your .m2 folder .

If it is not downloaded automatically for some reason manually install it using the mvn install:install command . See [Jars Issues in Maven Spring Hibernate Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708416/jars-issues-in-maven-spring-hibernate-project/8708530#8708530) for more probable solutions .

Try

1. Doing a mvn package and see if the Spring jar is in your war
2. After doing mvn eclipse:eclipse , refresh the eclipse ,clean your eclipse workspace - project- clean (Tick Build automatically)

open up the .classpath file and check for an entry similar to

or right click the project -->properties-->java build path-->libraries and see if the spring-web jar is there .

3. Open up the .m2 repo and see if the jar is inside the repo - If not do a install:install
4. do an mvn dependency:tree and see if the jar comes up .

That's pretty much what I can suggest

Comment: Dear Umesh, I am new to Spring. My web application is working fine in Struts2. I want to use spring for DI in my application. So I am trying to integrating. so now u can able to understand my situation.  I just take the code from MKYong website and trying to find the integration.

Comment: I have tried using external jar file in my project but it is showing the same error while deploying in server. I am in learning state of  maven and spring too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I Have downloaded Spring-web-2.5.6 jar file, placed in my classpath and restarted workspace still the error is showing like could not initialize the class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader. Placed my applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: @1010Logic please click the check mark on your screen next to my answer if you have accepted the answer . Thanks .

Comment: When i deploying my war file in server ,showing the error and couldn't get uploaded in server.Yes, I have specified my applicationContext file in Web.Xml file.                                                         <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>  
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param> 
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

Comment: @1010Logic See my edits - pretty much sumsup my suggestions :)